# Keys in LMDB for Caffe training

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I'm new to Caffe. The documentation is not clear for the topic of my question.

When creating training/test databases in LMDB for Caffe, do keys in the database have any sense for it?

In other words, does Caffe use any information from LMDB keys, or does it use just associated values, ignoring keys?

All examples, that I've found, establish some enumeration of data items and put pairs of (number-converted-to-string, datum) in the database. [Example](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/):

```
# create database, 
# open transaction
# ...
for i in range(N):
    datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()

    # add other attributes to datum

    str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)
    txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())
```

What if I assign some other unique value to `str_id` instead of a number-converted-to-string and submit it to `txn.put`?

Will the training result change?

The fact that it also can use HDF5 format that doesn't have keys, suggests that Caffe ignores them, but I'd like to be sure.

**Update** Am I correct in thinking that such enumeration in LMDB was established to emulate row index in LMDB, since LMDB is a key-value storage, while neural networks want tabular data?

Comment: why change the keys?

Comment: I want to add debug information about the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Any keys should be okay:

"LMDB stores arbitrary key/data pairs as byte arrays"

[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database)

Comment: I've updated my question. It is related to Caffe and how it interprets input data, not LMDB format itself.